# Populate a Grid with Pool of Items, Allowing Duplication, Guaranteeing Every Item is Present

Tags: algorithm, sorting, unique-constraint

I have a grid with size `100x100`. I have a pool of `n` items *(where `n` is less than `10000`)*.

I need to populate each section of the grid with one of the items in the pool where:

- Duplication is OK.
- Each of the `n` items in the pool **must** appear at least once.

I am randomly working through the sections of the grid, and for each I am iterating through the pool of items to determine a best-fit one *(based on specific, unrelated criteria)*.

I am interested in an efficient way to guarantee each item appears in the grid.

My first thought is something like this, however inefficient *(pseudo-code)*

```
shuffle(sections)     # randomize the order of the sections 
duplicate = pool.copy
section_assignments = []

for i in 0..1 - pool.size do
  best = findBest(sections[i], duplicate)
  duplicate.remove(best) # by removing the item from the duplicate pool
                         # it won't be used again until we want to allow
                         # duplicates
  section_assignments[i] = best
end

# by now all items from the pool now appear in the grid
# we can continue through the remaining sections; duplication
# at this point is OK

for j in  i..(sections.size - 1) do
  best = findBest(sections[j], pool)
  section_assignments[j] = best
end
```

The issue with an approach like this is as the `duplicate` pool's size shrinks, the accuracy between each section in the grid and the remaining items to choose a best-fit from may end up being quite far off.

I'm wondering if there is an alternative way, maybe using some sort of weighting of the items as they're used (allowing 'lighter' items to float to the top/have higher priority) which I can include in my best-fit algorithm to ensure every item in the pool does get used at least once.

Comment: Can you show your best fit algorithm?

Comment: Do you have a ranking or scoring for suitability function, or an n-best function, or only a way to find the single best fit? It seems like you could get a better solution for this problem if you were able to tell whether the second-best fit is very close or very far off.

Comment: @AbhishekBansal Unfortunately, no. The only detail of the algorithm that is relevant is the return value of the comparison between a section and each item in the pool: **a float value 'score'**. The lower the score, the better the fit. The item with the lowest score is the best fit.

Comment: @svk currently it returns the single best fit item - no persistent scoring/sorting is applied to the pool items for later inspection. When finding the best fit item I could definitely compare it's score to the score of the 2nd best if necessary.

Comment: I might be being dense, but your problem statement as it stands doesn't say anything about wanting to maximise fitness - your is-it-possible question has a simple answer of "yes, assign as many copies as needed of items `1` `2` ... `n` to the cells (which have been given some arbitrary ordering)"

Comment: ...so guessing that you want to maximise fitness, is there any further constraint - is there a *minimum* allowed fitness between item and cell?

Comment: An example: I have `60` shirts of varying material, size, color, etc... to give away. I have 25 people interested in taking a shirt. I know specific likes/dislikes of each individual with respect to their taste in shirts. I am randomly going to pick a shirt from the bin and then go through the 25 people to figure out who it's best for. Because I only have 25 people and all 60 shirts must go, some people will get more than one shirt. I want to ensure everyone will get shirts they like, but while **guaranteeing** everyone will get at least one shirt.

Comment: Regarding a *minimum*, what I'm trying to avoid is giving someone a shirt they hate. Using my psuedo-code above, if the 25th shirt I pull is black, and the 1 person who has no shirt yet LOVES white shirts, it wouldn't be ideal to give them the black shirt *just* because they don't yet have one, especially when there are 35 other shirts to look at.